# How to select uuid version in entity typeorm?

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs, typeorm

I'm use **typeorm** and **nestJs**

I have an entity in which I am using the decorator ***@PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')*** can I somehow specify a specific version of the uuid?

```js
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  uuid: string;
```

can it be done like this?

```js
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid:4') #?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [here](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/4656):

> TypeORM uses RFC4122 compliant UUID v4 function for drivers which do not have a built-in uuid function

So depending on the driver, you're already getting V4 UUID's.

If you need a different UUID implementation, then you can use something like the following to manually set the ID.  I've used this quite a lot for short ID's, and it works fine.

```
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';

  @PrimaryColumn()
  uuid: string = uuidv4()
```